# PowerShell AD - Create CSV with Group Membership Status

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I need to query an AD OU and list all the users with several attributes about their account and group membership.  The CSV format will be:

```
First Name  Last Name   SamAct         Active    New-UserGroup    Old-UserGroup
BIll        Gates       bill.gates     YES       YES              NO
Steve       Jobs        steve.jobs     NO        No               YES
```

The Yes, No are "Is he active' and "Is he a member of this group"

I have the following code almost done except I cannot figure out how to correctly determine if he is a group member or not.

Any advice??

```
function getADAccountStatus($adUserObj)
{
  if($adUserObj.AccountIsDisabled)
  { return "NO";}
  else { return "YES";}
}
function getNGStatus($adUserObj)
{
   if($_.memberof -contains 'New_Usergroup')
  {return "YES"; }
  else  {return "NO"; }
}

$ReportPath = "c:\scripts\report.csv"
$ou = 'OU=Group,DC=domain,DC=com'

$records = Get-QADUser -SearchRoot $ou | Select LastName,FirstName,SamAccountName,memberof

$records | foreach{

  new-object psobject -Property @{
  $LastName = $_.LastName
  $FirstName = $_.FirstName
  Account = $_.SamAccountName
  Active = getADAccountStatus($_)
  NG = getATCStatus($_)

  }} | Select $LastName,$FirstName,Account,Active,NG | Export-Csv $ReportPath -Force -ErrorAction Stop -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Please cleanup your code first. Lots of typos. ex. propertynames, functionnames, `getADAccountStatus($records)` instead of `getADAccountStatus($_)` etc. Also, the first to lines in the foreach-loop won't have any affect. The first/last name variables are set x amount of times and never used.

Comment: Here is tip [#5 Do use Hungarian Notation](http://windowsitpro.com/blog/what-do-not-do-powershell-part-5)

Comment: Are you using the Quest Active Directory module or the Window Remote Server Administration Tools (RSAT) Active Directory module? You're importing the RSAT module but using the Quest cmdlets.

Comment: JFTR: I usually recommend against using Hungarian Notation. In my experience it doesn't do any good with dynamically typed languages anyway, and I've seen *far* too many scripts with mismatches between variable name and actual value type (even in official code samples from Microsoft). Self-explanatory variable names are far more helpful than Hungarian Notation could ever hope to be.

Comment: Another point worth noting is that the `memberOf` attribute does not contain the user's primary group.

Comment: Cleaned up the code.  Trying to use Quest.  If not member of, how do I get a list of groups to query against by just the group name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `memberOf` attribute contains a list of the distinguished names of the user's secondary groups, so you'd have to check like this:

```
function getNGStatus($adUserObj) {
  $groupName = 'CN=New_Usergroup,CN=Users,DC=example,DC=com'
  if ($adUserObj.memberOf -contains $groupName) {
    return "YES"
  } else {
    return "NO"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i got to work:

```
function getADAccountStatus($adUserObj)
{
if($adUserObj.AccountIsDisabled)
{
    return "NO";
}
else
{
    return "YES";
}
}

function getNGStatus($adUserObj)
{   
$group = @(($_.MemberOf -split (“,”)  | Select-string -SimpleMatch "CN=") -replace “CN=”,”")
if($group -contains 'New_Usergroup')
{
    return "YES";
}
else
{
    return "NO";
}
}

$ReportPath = "c:\scripts\report.csv"
$ou = 'OU=Group,DC=domain,DC=com'

$records = Get-QADUser -SearchRoot $ou | Select LastName,FirstName,SamAccountName,memberof

$records | foreach{
new-object psobject -Property @{
LastName = $_.LastName
FirstName = $_.FirstName
Account = $_.SamAccountName
Active = getADAccountStatus($_)
NG = getNGStatus
}} | Select LastName,FirstName,Account,Active,NG | Export-Csv $ReportPath -Force -ErrorAction Stop -NoTypeInformation
```